# Count of duplicated values in a range, and the list of them

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

For exampe in the range below:

```
               A

 1          23213400
 2          25470790
 3          25630720
 4          23213400  'Here is a dupplucate happenes, 1
 5          23213400  'Here is a dupplucate happenes, 1
 6          26620401
 7          25470790  'Here is a dupplucate happenes, 2
 8          40029022
 9          22222290
 10         22222290  'Here is a dupplucate happenes, 3
```

In above, which values are duplucated: `23213400`,  `25470790`,  `22222290`.

---

I need returning the count of this values: **3**

And the list of this duplicated values:

```
               B
 1          23213400
 2          25470790
 3          22222290
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming data in `A1:A10`, with `B1` blank or text header use this array formula in `B2`

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,A$2:A$10)>1)*(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,A$1:A$10)=0),0)),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down column until you start getting blanks

See screenshot below
[image]